# Can I have selected-column highlighting in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I'm trying to get the whole column highlighted where my cursor is. The same way a line is highlighted, I'd like to get the column highlighted as well.

It exists in Atom, as shown below, as [an independent package](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-column).
[image]

I haven't found the same setting or package to do it in VS Code. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it's possible in the way `Atom` does it. There's no support for direct CSS applying. The decorations that exist do not support drawing on empty lines, some characters have different width (tab symbol). On the wrapped line it's going to affect only first visual line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get the exact same effect as with Atom, where you highlight a column, but for the same functionality (vertical line where your cursor is), you can install the extension [cursoruler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=freakone.cursoruler).

Answer (score 2):

I think Cursor Column Highlight is the best VS Code extension for this (it uses the `editor.lineHighlightBackground` color as vertical line in cursor position): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IuriiBarlukov.cursor-column-highlight

Comment: Yuris Auzins, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: This extension for VSCode does exactly what the author of the topic asks:
_"Adds cursor position indication with column highlighting.
Uses editor.lineHighlightBackground color as vertical line in cursor position. Improves cursor visibility, especially on big displays"._

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you the following extension: Editor Crosshair
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bitlang.vscode-crosshair

It adds horizontal and vertical rulers around the cursor (screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Just tried it, not bad but not perfect : the crosshair acts like a… crosshair ; it does not take the entire column and fill only a few lines